# Use SPListeItem properties inside an asp.net repeater

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using `<asp:repeater>` to display the items from a sharepoint list.

```
 foreach (SPListItem curItem in curItems)
{                                                                           
_itemUrl = curItem.Web.Url;
_listUrl = curItem.ParentList.Form[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url;
_itemId = curItem.ID;
}
```

ASP.net repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Title"] %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How can I display these properties:`curItem.Web.Url`, `curItem.ParentList.Form[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url` in the repeater like I did for "Title" field?
Like this:

```
<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Title"] %>
```

Any idea how it can be done and what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem).Web.Url %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

OR

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem).ParentList.Form[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

If you cast the data container, you can directly use the object as such.

Comment: Brian, thank you very much. Thank you, thank you, thank you a million times!!!!!! That was it.